# Subtitles displaying as boxes while playing videos in vlc on ubuntu 16.04 platform

Tags: 16.04, video, vlc, language-support, subtitle

I'm facing this problem while playing "Despacito". Is it happening because i need to install any language pack in my system or some other issue?
[Sample image of problem what i'm facing while playing this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggote.png)

Comment: Exactly. You need to have specific fonts if the language(s) use other than the Latin alphabet. Now, you can install the required fonts only but it's often easier to install the language pack at Settings > Language Support.

Comment: the subtitles were in regional language that's why it was happening but normal text editors are able to display those fonts but unfortunately not vlc. @MichaelBay

Comment: If you open the subtitle file with a text editor, does the text display correctly? And what language? Adding to your question a few lines with affected text from the subtitle file might help others confirm it.